# What English word is always spelled incorrectly?

Tags: wordplay, english, language

What word in the English language is always spelled incorrectly?

Comment: I'm surprised that folks don't like this one.  Okay, it's borderline joke, I admit, but it asks for a legitimate answer, no?

Comment: "Wrong." Wait, no. That's not right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a puzzle

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Incorrectly

Lol, that was an easy one.

Comment: The answer might be on the way to the rarely-awarded Reversal badge (provide an answer with at least 20 score to a question with a -5 or worse score) ^_^

Comment: @gatherer818 lol